# Transfer object good practices

Tags: java

I am asking a silly questions about a pojo that will be used only for serialisation (jackson -> json), not as a business object

- use public attributes
- use private attributes with public getters and setters

I wonder what is the difference in this case between a simple object with public attributes and one with private attributes but with public getters and setters.

I have to stress out this object will not be used as a business object later. Only for serialization as a REST response

Comment: Maybe a dupe: [Public fields in a Data Transfer Object](//stackoverflow.com/q/16539238)

Comment: About the difference between public attributes and getters/setters [here is a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1568230/1759845) about the benefits of getters and setters.

Comment: I don't think making the objects private would give you any benefit if you're just using it for serialisation. Since you're adding public getters & setters anyway you're just doing a bunch of work for no real reason. Think it would come down to personal preference & code style, but I would probably just make it public.